# Write a program to print the following pattern using for loop:

Tags: java

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 

my code 
     int ol = 39;
     for (ol= 00; ol<40; ol++) {
     System.out.print(ol); }
```

Above code prints in a straight line. I want to print it in the above pattern. I have tried with print& printfn. I am learning java on my own. I am unable to find the right code to print in the above pattern.

Comment: The basic logic would be to keep a counter variable that you increment inside the loop. When the variable reaches 10, you add a `println("")` and then reset the counter to 0, for the next 10.

Comment: Try consider using only 1 loop and then use modulo `%` to test if your loop variable `ol + 1 % 10 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  But since you are starting out I would recommend:

Using nested loops.

- The outer one from 0 to 3 inclusive.
- The inner one from 0 to 9 inclusive.

Then establish a counter, initialized to 0 and print out its value. Then increment it.

To get the leading 0 use `System.out.printf("%02d ", counter)` to print. You can also use a conditional (if statement) and prepend a 0 when necessary.

And print a new line after every 10 values.

For more information on formatted printing using `printf` check out
[PrintStream.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use 1 for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(String.format("%02d ", i));
}
```